# React-intl use json tree format

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, internationalization, react-intl

I use react-intl in my project and I load json files for any language but I need my json file have a tree format. When I load my component react-intl printing the key string of json.
For example:

```
{ 
 "header":{
  "title": "My title",
  "text": "My text"
 },
 "footer":{
  "title": "My title",
  "text": "My text"
 } 
}
```

When I use:

`<p><FormattedMessage id="header.title"/></p>`

the result is:
`<p>header.title</p>`

Any idea?

Comment: post your app.js file

Comment: At the moment i find **Flatten messages Object** in the react-intl [doc](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/Upgrade-Guide#flatten-messages-object) Thanks @Shota

Comment: Please find my answer from here. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/50810710/1230432](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50810710/1230432)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react-intl - accessing nested messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45783677/react-intl-accessing-nested-messages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this without **"Flatten messages Object"**, you can use FormattedMessage like this:

```
<FormattedMessage id="header">
  {txt => <span>{txt[title]}</span>}
</FormattedMessage>
```

Result will be: "My title"

or of course:

```
<FormattedMessage id="footer">
  {txt => <span>{txt[text]}</span>}
</FormattedMessage>
```

Result will be: "My Text"

Answer (score 1):

I find the **Flatten messages Object** of official [doc](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/Upgrade-Guide#flatten-messages-object)

```
function flattenMessages(nestedMessages, prefix = '') {
 return Object.keys(nestedMessages).reduce((messages, key) => {
    let value       = nestedMessages[key];
    let prefixedKey = prefix ? `${prefix}.${key}` : key;

    if (typeof value === 'string') {
        messages[prefixedKey] = value;
    } else {
        Object.assign(messages, flattenMessages(value, prefixedKey));
    }

    return messages;
 }, {});
}

let messages = flattenMessages(nestedMessages);
```