# react-intl - accessing nested messages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-intl

I'm trying to use `react-intl` package inside an app. The app is rendered on the server so I wrote some code to determine which language to use and serve into `IntlProvider`.

Translations were provided in `messages.js` file and they look like this:

```
export default {
  en: {
    message: '...some message',
    nested: {
      anotherMessage: '...another message',
    }
  }
  de: {
    // ...
  }
}
```

What I do is something like this:

```
// import messages from './messages.js'
// Check the locale for the user (based on cookies or other things)
const locale = ...
// Get the required messages
const messagesForLocale= = messages[locale];
// Supply the messages to the IntlProvider
<IntlProvider locale={locale} messages={messagesForLocale}>
  // ...
</IntlProvider>
```

Then when I use `FormattedMessage` component I can't access the nested message (`anotherMessage`) with code like this:

```
<FormattedMessage id="nested.anotherMessage" ... />
```

But `message` is accessible.

Any ideas where I made the mistake, or maybe I'm missing something in the whole concept?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Since React Intl v2 no longer supports nested messages objects, the messages need to be [flattened](https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/upgrade-guide-2x/#flatten-messages-object).

```
export const flattenMessages = ((nestedMessages, prefix = '') => {
  if (nestedMessages === null) {
    return {}
  }
  return Object.keys(nestedMessages).reduce((messages, key) => {
    const value       = nestedMessages[key]
    const prefixedKey = prefix ? `${prefix}.${key}` : key

    if (typeof value === 'string') {
      Object.assign(messages, { [prefixedKey]: value })
    } else {
      Object.assign(messages, flattenMessages(value, prefixedKey))
    }

    return messages
  }, {})
})

// Use flattenMessages
<IntlProvider locale={locale} messages={flattenMessages(messagesForLocale)}>
```

refs:

- https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/Upgrade-Guide#flatten-messages-object
- https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/issues/162#issuecomment-139683466

Comment: Thanks for that. We decided to go with `I18next` as this seems to be a more flexible library.

Comment: Didn't know that `react-intl` started at Yahoo!

Answer (score 16):

`react-intl` does not support nested messages anymore. If you still want to organize your messages that way, you can use the [`flat`](https://github.com/hughsk/flat) library to correct your messages structure beforehand.

```
import flatten from 'flat'

<IntlProvider locale={locale} messages={flatten(messagesForLocale)}>
```

A contributor of `react-intl` claims that the main reason for only supporting a flat message structure is:

> Simplicity and flexibility is the main reason. With the flat object, people can write whatever message ids/keys they want and they won't be interpreted with special semantics.

View the issue [Support nested messages-object](https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs/issues/207)
 comment on GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, customization using **flattenMessages** is the best way I found.

Here is the video demo for your reference.

https://egghead.io/lessons/react-convert-a-hard-coded-string-using-react-intl-formattedmessage